# multi-instances of API Platform using docker for multi tenancy - efficiency, best paractices, etc.?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, api-platform.com

I am building web-based app using API Platform Distribution, single-tenant by nature for simplicity and to speed up the development but to deploy it for more than one tenant (10-30), each will have separate subdomains and user data (files and databases).

For now I am considering two approaches:

1. Simplest one using API Platform Distribution as it is - for each tenant new API Platform Distribution instance (set of containers) is started, for example:

```
docker-composer -p tenant1 --env-file .env.tenant1 up
docker-composer -p tenant2 --env-file .env.tenant2 up
(...)
```

2. One instance of API Platform distribution with virtual hosting (caddy docker?) so each tenant is directed to separate ROOT/APP DIR with its own config set (different database name, data directory, themes etc.).

First approach is the simplest one using API Platform Distribution as it is, but the question of resource consumption immediately arises, will it be efficient enough with multi docker containers (caddy, php-fpm, postresql, NodeJS/NextJS or static generated during build)?  We are talking about 10-30 instances/ tenants.

Anybody had experience here or any recommendation for solving this with api-platform?